# I tried this javascript code of simple if else block Error:-Declaration or statement expected

Tags: javascript, if-statement, coding-style

`constant bill = 275;`
`let tip = 0;`
`let total = 0;`
`if (bill > 50 && bill < 300);`
`{`
`tip = 0.15 * bill;`
`console.log("tip", tip, "bill", bill)`
`}`
`else if (bill < 50 || bill > 300);`
`{`
`tip = 0.20 * bill;`
`console.log("tip", tip, "bill", bill)`
`}`
 `else`
`{`
`console.log("No tip")`
`}`
`total = bill + tip;`
`console.log("total", total)`

I tried this javascript code of simple if else block  Error:-Declaration or statement expected. Why code is not working??

Comment: Remove the semicolons after the if statements: `if(condition); {//do something}` => `if(condition) {//do something}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's `const` and not `constant`

```
 const bill = 275;
      let tip = 0;
      let total = 0;
      if (bill > 50 && bill < 300) {
        tip = 0.15 * bill;
        console.log("tip", tip, "bill", bill);
      } else if (bill < 50 || bill > 300) {
        tip = 0.2 * bill;
        console.log("tip", tip, "bill", bill);
      } else {
        console.log("No tip");
      }
      total = bill + tip;
      console.log("total", total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are doing a mistake by putting a semi colon right after ')' bracket of your if condition. when you do this it means you are declaring an empty block for that if condition

```
constant bill = 275;
let tip = 0; 
let total = 0; 
if (bill > 50 && bill < 300) { 
  tip = 0.15 * bill; 
  console.log("tip", tip, "bill", bill)
}else if (bill < 50 || bill > 300) {
  tip = 0.20 * bill; 
  console.log("tip", tip, "bill", bill)
}else { 
  console.log("No tip") 
} 
total = bill + tip;
console.log("total", total)
```

Here I corrected the mistake you made...